# How to see what has been checked into git, but hasn't been committed to svn via dcommit?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, commit

I'm using git-svn. How can I get a list of what I've committed into git, but haven't yet committed to the SVN repository since the last `git svn dcommit`? That is, how can I verify what is about to be sent if I do a dcommit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `--dry-run` option for `git svn dcommit` is very useful for finding out exactly what will be committed to Subversion.  In particular that has the properties that:

- It doesn't actually commit anything to Subversion
- It tells you which diffs will be calculated to create new revisions in Subversion
- It tells you which branch in Subversion you will be committing to - this is sometimes non-obvious, since it is taken from the Subversion branch specified in the first ancestor commit with a git-svn-id in its commit message

In general it's a good idea to do `git svn rebase` before even thinking about using `dcommit`, so that your history is linearized - otherwise merge commits may not make much sense in the Subversion history.  (If you've done that, then `git log` and `gitk --all` will also be essentially equivalent, but I think `git svn dcommit --dry-run` gives you a more accurate picture of what's about to happen, even if it's more difficult to interpret.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I think is to do this using gitk. You will want the --all option to see all branches. If you have not used it before simply type:

```
gitk --all
```

You will see a graphical view of your branches. When you update from SVN, you essentially do a rebase (git svn rebase). This means any local commits that are not checked in to SVN will appear on the branch after the last SVN commit. Basically look at the commits between your remote SVN trunk and your master branch.

Answer (score 1):

I use `git log --oneline --graph`:

```
* aaaaaaa commit message
*   bbbbbbb commit message 
|\  
| * ccccccc commit message
| * ddddddd commit message
| * eeeeeee commit message
|/  
*   fffffff commit message 
|\  
...
```

It's easy to see that commits `aaaaaaa`, `bbbbbbb`, and `fffffff` are on the current (master) branch.  These commits either have already been or will be committed to Subversion the next time you execute `git svn dcommit`.  (Commits `ccccccc`, `ddddddd`, `eeeeeee` are on a separate branch which was merged into master and will not be committed to Subversion *as separate commits*.)

Comment: It's worth being clear that the changes introduced in `ccccccc`, `ddddddd` and `eeeeeee` will end up in Subversion, since the diff calculated for the merge commit `ffffffff` will include the changes back to `bbbbbbbb`, assuming the first parent of `ffffffff` is `bbbbbbbb`, as you suggest by saying that branch was "merged into master".  Those changes won't appear as separate revisions, though, so the results may be less than ideal - it's safest to do `git svn rebase` first if you want to commit such history to Subversion.

Comment: @Mark Longair: My intent was to allay any fears that `ccccccc`, `ddddddd` and `eeeeeee` would appear in Subversion as separate commits.  In my experience, those commits often constitute a feature branch and would not be suitable as separate Subversion commits.

Answer (score 1):

To just see the list of commits, here's my magic:

```
git svn dcommit -n  | sed 1d | cut -d" " -f3 | xargs -I{} git log --oneline --no-walk {}
```

output:

```
c2e1eff changed a thing
a889dbf changed a second thing
18a4653 undid the second thing-- oops
```