# How to see 'git svn dcommit' changes before dcommitting?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

With `svn-git`, how can I see what is about to be committed
with `git svn dcommit`?

Here are the commands I run:

```
git svn  clone file:///svn/test1 test1-git
cd test1-git
echo "first line" > test1.txt 
git add test1.txt 
git commit
```

Now it's committed to the git repository -- good. But before I run `git svn dcommit` I'd like to see a diff that contains the changes that would be committed to the SVN repository.

Comment: Have you found an answer ?

Answer (score 16):

If your remote branch is called `git-svn` (it is called that if you just do a plain `git svn clone`) then you can see a diff between the current branch and  `git-svn`:

```
git diff git-svn HEAD
```

You would see all changes that are present in your current branch but not in the svn repository.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I followed the advise when cloning and added the prefix origin/ so my remote branch is 'remotes/origin/trunk'. Thus I had to use `git diff origin/trunk HEAD`. The log version is also nice: `git log origin/trunk..HEAD`.

Answer (score 9):

The output of 'git svn dcommit --dry-run' can be fed to git again like so:

```
git diff-tree 2282c630eeef26fecbc3f3519be55a9dce094c80~12282c630eeef26fecbc3f3519be55a9dce094c80 -u
```

Note the '-u' at the end.
You will then see a diff.

If you just want to see something like 'svn stat' you can use '--stat':

```
krausem-> git diff-tree f00e37882b7186e9e7f38c2fa28778e39734e2e7~1 f00e37882b7186e9e7f38c2fa28778e39734e2e7 --stat
 .../src/main/webapp/tiles/vertrag/freiKlauseln.jsp |    9 +++++++++
 1 files changed, 9 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Second Answer**  (Revised after comments indicating --dry-run wasn't sufficient)

Depending on your expectations, it *might* work to use git log like this:

```
git log remotes/svn.. --oneline
```

Note the two periods at end. That will show all commits on current branch since the last shared parent. In the case of typical git-svn usage, this would be all local commits since the last dcommit.   (This assumes your remote SVN branch name is "remotes/svn". You can run "git branch -a" to list all branches.)  It's important to understand what this is doing versus just running it verbatim, but perhaps this provides more of what you are looking for.

---

**First Answer**

You can use --dry-run with dcommit:

```
git svn dcommit --dry-run
```

See this duplicate question/answer: [How to see what has been checked into git, but hasn't been committed to svn via dcommit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038829/how-to-see-what-has-been-checked-into-git-but-hasnt-been-committed-to-svn-via) .

Comment: That doesn't show any useful diff, just something like `Committing to file:///svn/test1 ...
diff-tree e8e4449bbf534d373694194873ea6a9ed41517bf~1 e8e4449bbf534d373694194873ea6a9ed41527be`

Comment: I edited my answer with another idea. To be clear though, although the `svn dcommit --dry-run` isn't easy to interpret, it is precise regarding what is about to be committed to SVN from GIT point-of-view.

Comment: After seeing Tomas's answer, I realized I'm not sure what you actually wanted. A diff of actual changes, or a log of commits that haven't been dcommited yet.  My answers obviously provide the latter.

Answer (score 1):

When I am in the situation of starting a `git svn dcommit`, I first open `gitk` and ask it to show me the commits to be transferred:

```
gitk git-svn..
```

This assumes that your upstream SVN repo is really called `git-svn` as [Tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110825/tomas-markauskas) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9776318/520162). If you're unsure about the name of your upstream SVN repo, simply start `gitk` and search for a branch that you didn't create (and sounds Git-SVN-ish).